# Rotating a 2D image with Permutation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, linear-transformations, rotations

As I understand, permutation matrices are rotation matrix with even permutation corresponds to a proper rotation and odd permutation corresponds to an improper rotation.

Does not that mean that, If I multiply a binary image (simply a matrix of 0s and 1s), I get a rotation of the image ?.  But I do not get it.  What does exactly happens ?. Can anyone please explain to me ?

Comment: Permutation matrices are orthogonal matrices with determinant either +1 or -1 same like rotation matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A permutation matrix (call it $P$) is a nonsingular (hence, square) matrix where all elements are zero except for one element on each row which is $1$.

Consider now any square matrix $A$ (maybe, an image) and let
$$ B = PA$$
then, if the $i$th element of row $j$ is $1$, this means that the $j$th row of $B$ is equal to the $i$th row of $A$. For instance, if i have two matrices

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
     0 &   0     &0 &    0    & 0\\
     0 &   1     &1  &   0   &  0\\
     0 &   1    & 0   &  1  &   0\\
     0 &   1   &  0   &  1 &    0\\
     0 &   1  &   1   &  0&     0
\end{pmatrix},
\quad
P = \begin{pmatrix}
     1 &   0     &0 &    0    & 0\\
     0 &   0     & 0   &   1   &  0\\
     0 &   0    & 1   &  0  &   0\\
     0 &   1   &  0   &  0 &    0\\
     0 &   0  &   0   &  0&     1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then, the result would be

$$ B = PA = \begin{pmatrix}
     0 &   0     &0 &    0    & 0\\
     0 &   1    & 0   &  1  &   0\\
     0 &   1   &  0   &  1 &    0\\
   0 &   1     &1  &   0   &  0\\
     0 &   1  &   1   &  0&     0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
or, in pictures

[image]

You could say that they are rotation matrices but I don't know if that will give you more intuition as to how they work. I believe thinking of them as "row swappers" is more intuitive and useful.

If we postmultiply by the permutation matrix, you get the same effect but for the columns (so a $1$ element in position $i$ in row $j$ means that column $j$ in the output was column $i$ in the input); so doing $AP$ would give you

[image]

A rotation matrix would allow you to perform similar operations, but the rows of the output would be combinations of the rows of the input (with $\sin$ and $\cos$ relationships).

Comment: I suppose OP doesn't take into account that rotation is applied to **coordinates** of pixels not to **values** of pixels. Only $2 \times 2$ permutation matrix  ( 2 coordinates) has sense in this context.

Comment: I think that seeing a rotation matrix in action on an image may clarify that it is not a "rotation of the image" as you would do in an image processing software.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, it can be confusing to think of rotating a matrix that represents an "image", since a $90$ degree rotation, for example, would make you think that a matrix that is $m$ x $n$ should now become $n$ x $m$. But this is not true, since rotation matrices are square. So instead of thinking of it like multiplying by the rotation matrix, I would suggest thinking of it as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/695130/3813411) post - in other words, you should take each pixel in the "output" matrix, and apply the inverse transformation matrix and look at the corresponding pixel in the "input" matrix.